# Remove H3 element on the fly

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I need to remove a H3 element on the fly (meaning when the page start load the DOM). So the H3 is whithin a DIV with ID="category_rss_widgets" and the H3 looks like:

```
<h3 class="widget-title"></h3>
```

I think in do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#category_rss_widgets').remove('widget-title');
});
```

Is this code right? I didn't test it so I made by head
Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: @undefined all of yours are right but I read the code and have my doubts so I prefer to ask here where experts are my bad aparently

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#category_rss_widgets').find('.widget-title').remove();
```

Comment: Should be `.find('.widget-title')` to match on a class name.

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you just try it out?

Having said that, your code won't work as is. Don't pass a selector to `.remove()`, because that filters the set of matched elements, it doesn't search for descendants of the matched elements. Instead you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#category_rss_widgets h3.widget-title').remove();
});
```

The selector `'#category_rss_widgets h3.widget-title'` will match any h3 elements with the "widget-title" class that are descendants of #category_rss_widgets. Note that to match on a class name you need a `.` before the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.widget-title').remove();
});
```

You are passing the selector to .remove() method which will filter the matched elements..